# Domain policy files on java phones

Tags: java, java-me, cross-domain-policy

Anybody knows there are any tools available to view domain policy files on Java phones?

Help is highly appreciable.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can only do that on Symbian phones, using a file browser application developed in C++ and with high enough capability (the application may have to be trusted by the handset manufacturer) to look at firmware files (the Z: drive).

You might want to try the S^3 FileBrowser at http://symbian-coderus.blogspot.co.uk/

Samsung Bada phones might also allow it.